# How to use msbuild restore in CICD with credentials for private feed?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, cicd

I have an annoying problem with my C# projects that are restored, built and pushed in CI/CD.

We are using Concourse for our CI/CD and I have credentials setup in environment variables, which are passed through to scripts building the project.

However, using `msbuild /t:restore` is not working, since I cannot provide username or password as a property or parameter. Instead, it has an option to provide a `nuget.config`.

My issue with having to provide a `nuget.config` is the fact, that I need to check it into source control.
Now, the actual password in the checked in `nuget.config` is still encrypted, but **IT IS NOT** synchronized with our keycloak vault. I would have to recreate this damn `nuget.config` every time, the password changes and without it, the build BREAKS.

This is my call to **msbuild** in the script:

```
$buildExit = Invoke-MsBuild $target.FullName, `
                "/t:restore", `
                "/p:RestoreConfigFile=$env:nuget_config", `
                # "/p:RestoreSources=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%3B$env:external_source", `
                "/p:RestorePackagesConfig=true", `
                "/p:RestoreNoCache=true", `
                "/p:RestoreForce=true"
                # "/p:NuGetInteractive=true"
                # "/p:Username=$env:repo_username", `
                # "/p:Password=$env:repo_password"
```

The commented out portions of the command are my attempts of making it work. **It does not work using those commented properties instead of `/p:RestoreConfigFile`.**

**How am I supposed to use `msbuild /t:restore` with a private nuget feed and corresponding credentials?**

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target) is very unclear about this.

**Note:**
It is important in our CI/CD, that the build agent is **NOT persistent**, meaning I can't just set up a config locally on the build agent, which would solve the problem.
I need to provide the credentials via environment variables or some other form of non-persistent methods.

Comment: Usually you copy the [nuget config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) which has the [credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials) set as environment variables.

Comment: How would that look like? Like in the example?

Comment: I just noticed in the 2nd documentation you linked there's an example using environment variables.

Comment: Yes, the second link should have the example.

Comment: nuget's docs for nuget.config has examples showing how to use environment variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments and [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials), the solution to the problem is to use environment variables inside the `nuget.config`, like so:

```xml
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        <add key="private-feed" value="https://private-feed.com/repository/nuget/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <private-feed>
            <add key="Username" value="%repo_username%" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%repo_password%" />
        </private-feed>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

I overlooked that example, apparently, as I was too focused on the documentation of msbuild.